# Python Hydra- Is there any way to print config path and file using hydra compose api?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, fb-hydra

I need to get the list of config directory/path name and files inside the config path from below directory

```
Main_dir:
 conf:
  project:
    test_project1:
      env:
        source:
            src.yaml
            src2.yaml
        dest:
            dest.yaml
            dest2.yaml
        other1.yaml
        other2.yaml
```

i tried with below compose api

```
with initialize(version_base=None, config_path="../../conf"):
 config_dir = os.path.join(get_original_cwd(), "test_project1/env")
 print(cfg)
```

Expected: i need to get all config and yaml from the "test_project/env"

```
source:
        src.yaml
        src2.yaml
dest:
        dest.yaml
        dest2.yaml
other1.yaml
other2.yaml
```

But i am getting error says

```
get_original_cwd() should be used after HydraConfig is initalized
```

Any solution to this?